# Migrating to android Q app install failed

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have migrated my android project to android q in android studio canary but whenever I try to run my project on my Google Pixel 2. I am getting this error I have also uninstalled the previous version of the app. I have done everything clean project rebuild invalidate the cache, **but still see below error log:**

```
11:40 AM    Failed to commit install session 1536794838 with command cmd package install-commit 1536794838. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2
11:40 AM    Session 'app': Changes were not applied.
                    The application could not be installed: UNKNOWN_ERROR
                    Retry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add below in your `manifest.xml` inside `application` tag

```
android:extractNativeLibs="false"
```

This flag is to indicate whether or not the package installer should extract the native libraries from the APK to the filesystem. If set to `false`, then your native libraries must be page aligned and stored uncompressed in the APK. Hence, after setting it to `false`, you should also have below options configured in your `build.gradle`

```
packagingOptions{
    doNotStrip "*/armeabi/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/x86_64/*.so"
}
```

Comment: by setting it true it helps can you explain why it happening?

Comment: android:extractNativeLibs="true"
 is working not false

Comment: Yes, i saw that. Just be aware that marking it as true means `the package installer will extract the native libraries from the APK to the filesystem`. By setting it to `false` and applying the `packagingOptions` said above should also work.